# Gravity form API Permission denied

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I started following [this github tutorial](https://github.com/ibjects/Gravity-Forms-API-Client-iOS) It successfully `GET` all entries and `POST` data to a form.
So after that as I move forward I wanted to add search filters with my GET call. After a lot of researching and trying different approaches I get to the point that I always get

```
{
status: 401,
response: "Permission denied"
}
```

as my JSON response. Following this I implemented search but it didn't work: https://www.stevenhenty.com/gravity-forms-api/#filter_entries

By consulting some php people they told me it's permission issue your call is correct. So I went [here](https://www.stevenhenty.com/gravity-forms-api/#security) and tried both methods *WordPress  Cookie Authentication* and *External Clients: Signature Authentication* but the response is the same.

I'm using the Cookie `NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@?_gf_json_nonce=%@",BaseURLString,route,[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]];` The `_gf_json_nonce` after searching I got that it'll be the UDID of the phone so that is why I'm using that.
 If I use the other signature one I use it as `NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@?api_key=%@&signature=%@&expires=%@",BaseURLString,route,api_key,signature,expires];` the result is the same.
So if I want to use any of this call with search filters I'm doing this

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"key": @"2",
                             @"value": @"my@email.com",
                             @"operator": @"contains"};

    NSMutableDictionary *modify = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [modify  setObject:params forKey:@"field_filters"];


    [manager GET:stringURL  parameters:modify progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
```

So any ideas how to get it authenticate so that the call can start working.

**UPDATE**
 1: I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38925716/gravity-forms-api-always-401) but it didn't work. I've also commented on it.

Comment: Please post a sample of a successful GET request using the signature to retrieve all entries. And also a sample unsuccessful request to the same endpoint but with the search param.

Comment: @StevenHenty see the updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the search param set to a URL encoded JSON string like this:

```
http://yourdomain/gravityformsapi/forms/3/entries/?api_key=[snip]&signature=[snip]%3D&expires=[snip]&search={%22field_filters%22:%20[{%22key%22:%20%222%22,%20%22value%22%20:%20%@gmailcom%22,%20%22operator%22%20:%20%22contains%22}]}
```

So, a bit easier to read, the search param would look something like this:

```
{
  "field_filters": [
    {
      "key": "2",
      "value": "@gmail.com",
      "operator": "contains"
    }
  ]
}
```